# Dockers networking

Tags: networking, containers, virtual-machine, suse

I have a scenario where I want to establish a communication between the docker container running inside a Virtual machine and console (the VM is present on the same console). This work is to be done on SUSE Linux. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Create a external `nat` int the host using something `docker network create.
Mention this network while creating the container.

Comment: The host is SUSE Sles 11 and the docker requires SUSE Sles12 which is running on the VM and the docker is installed on this VM.